# Trying a multivariate analyses on time series (with R)

Tags: time-series, anova, correspondence-analysis, qualitative

I got measures of one variable (that behaves as a time series) for different conditions (some quantitatives, but mostly are qualitatives).

For example, this is a "fake" representative plot of this variable for 2 differents conditions :

http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=140415020040937841.png

How can I statistically point out difference for my measured variable using Correspondence analysis methods?